# GetOleDbSchemaTable throws exception becaues it doesn't find the object sheet$'Print_Area'

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledbconnection

I'm trying to expose the column names from excel in a vb.net application. The code looks like this.

```
Dim EXCEL_CONNECTION_TEMPLATE As String =
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'"
Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(String.Format(EXCEL_CONNECTION_TEMPLATE, savePath))
    con.Open()
    Dim schema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, Nothing)
    DoStuffWith(schema)
End Using
```

After execution i get an exception throwed by GetOleDbSchemaTable:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object
>   ''sheetname $'Print_Area'.  Make sure the object exists and that you
>   spell its name and the path name correctly.
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException

It looks like, that `GetOleDbSchemaTable` has some problem with the sheetnames if they contains space and has print area defined with it on the same time.

Tried to supply parameters like:

```
Dim schema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, "sheetname $"})
```

This way it didn't throwed the exception but returned with no value.

Any tip / workaround / suggestion is welcomed. And it's obviously not an option to ask the users not to include space and print area in the excel file they uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

It seems that if any of the sheet names in the uploaded excel file contains space, the oledb wraps it between single quote. This seems to working now:

```
Dim schema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, "'sheetname $'"})
```